# Error reading characters of string when setting 2d array values

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I got 3 files: 
1.  main.c 
2.  testarray.c 
3.  header.h

I want to create global variable name 'arrayTwoD' which is a 2d array. At 'testarray.c' I want to initialize the array and fill with values with 's'. This function will be called on 'main.c'.

Here's my codes: 

 headerfile.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

void iniTwoDArray();

/*global variable 2d array not sure im doing correctly or not*/
extern char *arrayTwoD[2][3];
```

testarray.c

```
#include "headerfile.h"
#include <stdio.h>

char *arrayTwoD[2][3];

void iniTwoDArray() {
   /*not sure if this is a good way to set the values */
    memset(arrayTwoD, 's', sizeof(arrayTwoD[0][0]) * 2 * 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%c", arrayTwoD[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

main.c

```
#include "headerfile.h"

int main() {
    iniTwoDArray();
    return 0;
}
```

While debugging, in testarray.c, the line below keep showing "Error reading characters of string" after it got executed. The error is shown in the screenshot below. I just started learning C, would really appreciate if you can explain to me in layman terms.

```
memset(arrayTwoD, 's', sizeof(arrayTwoD[0][0]) * 2 * 3);
```

[image]

Comment: It's supposed to be `char arrayTwoD[2][3];`? not `char *array...`

Comment: `char *arrayTwoD[2][3];` is a 2D array of *pointers* to `char`. Just leave out the `*` then it will be a 2D array of `char`.

Comment: `char *arrayTwoD[2][3];` is 2D array of `char*`, that is of *pointers* to `char`, not of `char`. Mind the star.

Comment: @WeatherVane: ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's the debugger trying to be helpful\clever - it's seeing your array of chars and assuming it is string.
Try doing a watch instead of looking at the auto's window, it might decode your variable better\correctly.

FYI: you could just do memset (arrayTwoD, 's', sizeof (arrayTwoD))

Comment: Thanks! It solves another issue i was facing. sizeof(arrayTwoD[0][0]) * 2 -1 * 3 -1 Somehow u cant minus the integer there. Do u know why? Secondly, I have tried adding the array into watch. Still showing the error.

Comment: *it's seeing your array of chars and assuming it is string* There is no difference between "array of chars" and "text string" and the compiler doesn't care. The asker is using uninitialized pointer and it crashes...